# UserLoginInfo contains ProviderKey. Is it specific to individual users

Tags: .net, oauth, asp.net-mvc-5, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity

UserLoginInfo as a parameter in

```
 Task<Users> IUserLoginStore<CODE.Users, string>.FindAsync(UserLoginInfo login)
```

Contains providerkey. the above method `FindAsync` gets provider key and returns User. I like to know is if there are two users use external login through `facebook` when they login, will there be different provider key for both of these users. And Is the provider Key remains the same. If not

Then how `FindAsync` search for user in local db? and returns it

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On MSDN, it states about `ProviderKey` as

> Gets the user specific key for the login provider.

So its user specific means every user will have different `ProviderKey`s.